# Cannot connect AS400 by python

Tags: python, db2, ibm-midrange

I am using idb_bm module to build the connection to the AS400 by using the following code.

```
from ibm_db import connect

connection = connect('DATABASE=DATABASE;'
                     'HOSTNAME=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;'
                     'PORT=446;'
                     'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
                     'UID=uid;'
                     'PWD=pwd;', '', '')
```

After execute the code, it shows the following error,

```
connection = connect('DATABASE=DATABASE;'
 SQLCODE=-30061][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "DATABASE          " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004
```

The AS400 structure is complicated with tons of library and tons of table in each library. What's the database alias or database name actually? I have stuck to it for few days....Thanks all.

Comment: Ask your AS400 admin. We cannot guess your database name!

Comment: @mao I just want to make sure it is caused by the the wrong database name.

Comment: Your symptom is caused by the *absence* of a valid database name, but those names are site specific, that is the reason you should ask your admin. Another approach is to use other tools that connect to the desired database and look at their configuration to find the database name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have a modern POWER server running IBM i and not a 20 year old AS/400...

Download [IBM Access Client Solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) (ACS)..

Set up a connection to your IBM i.

The "Schemas" component of ACS will show you a list of databases on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're connecting to the local database and not an iASP, you should be able to use `*LOCAL`.